# What grammar is used in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> I don’t feel like I usually do

Actually I don’t get how it is structured in terms of grammar.
But i guess it is the same as this sentence:

> I don’t feel like doing what I usually do

It seems to me that first one is wrong, but it is right.
Please, explain why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, *do* is an auxiliary verb that replaces the verb *feel* that is mentioned earlier in the sentence. This is a common thing for auxiliaries in English. Thus, your sentence can be rewritten as follows:

> I don't feel like I usually **feel**.

That's what it is actually saying. So, your interpretation is wrong.

Compare your example with this short dialogue:

> — Do you feel like you **got the answer right**?
>   — Honestly, I don't feel like I **got it right**. / Honestly, I don't feel like I **did**.

What we have done here is replace *got it right* with something shorter, namely *did*. The auxiliary verb *did* tells us two things: what happened is in the past tense and the information about what actually happened is mentioned somewhere earlier in the dialogue.

Answer (score 0):

The two sentences you give are not the same (although both are perfectly grammatical).

> I don’t feel like I usually do.

Expands to:

> I do not feel like I usually feel.

The "do" in the first sentence acts as a placeholder that refers back to the previously stated main verb "feel."